# React/redux, displaying multiple components, sharing same actions, but with different state

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say I have a reusable container. It is a wizard with multiple pages.

The wizard state is driven by redux/actions. When an action is fired, I use a reducer to update my state.

What if I want to have multiple wizards duplicated, with it's own state?

I am thinking there must be a way to have actions handled by a certain dynamic reducer (that can be created/destroyed), and then have each individual wizard driven from these dynamic pieces of the store/state.

Is this recommended? Are the libraries out there that make this easier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just partition your main state into as many wizard states as you need and send a wizard id along with each action so that your reducer knows which one to tackle.

## As Array

```
{
  wizards: [
    { id: 'A', state: true },
    { id: 'B', state: false },
    { id: 'C', state: true }
  ]
}
```

You can write a wizard reducer which understands how to reduce a single wizard state.

```
function wizardReducer(wizard, action) {
  switch(action) {
    case 'TOGGLE':
      return {
        id: wizard.id,
        state: !wizard.state
      };
    default:
      return wizard;
  }
}
```

Then write a `wizardsReducer` which understands how to reduce a list of wizards.

```
function wizardsReducer(wizards, action) {
  return wizards.map(function(wizard) {
    if(action.id == wizard.id) {
      return wizardReducer(wizard, action);
    } else {
      return wizard;
    }
  });
}
```

Finally, use `combineReducers` to create a root reducer which delegates responsibility for the `wizards` property to this `wizardsReducer`.

```
combineReducers({
  wizards: wizardsReducer
});
```

## As Object

If you're storing your wizards in an object instead, you'll have to construct your `wizardsReducer` slightly differently.

```
{
  wizards: {
    A: { id: 'A', state: true },
    B: { id: 'B', state: false },
    C: { id: 'C', state: true }
  }
}
```

It wouldn't make much sense to map over the states, when we can just select the state we need straight away.

```
function wizardsReducer(wizards, action) {
  if(!(action.id in wizards)) return wizards;

  const wizard = wizards[action.id];
  const updatedWizard = wizardReducer(wizard, action);

  return {
    ...wizards,
    [action.id]: updatedWizard
  };
}
```

Comment: Should my react components generate the unique id? Where do I store/scope the id? In the state of the component? Should I have actions for CREATE/DESTROY that are fired in the mount/unmount of the component?

Comment: Most of those questions depend on the lifetime and purpose of the individual wizards in your application. If there is a truly 1 - 1 relationship between wizard states and wizard components, then all of those suggestions sound reasonable.

Comment: I found a nice redux library that might make this a little simpler. There are others out there as well. https://github.com/tonyhb/redux-ui

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for a lib for this, so I am just throwing it here.

I created infra functions which will intercept the actions and add `meta-data` to each action. (following `FSA`)
You can use this easily to create multiple containers without them affecting each other.

[reducer-action-interceptor](https://github.com/jony89/reducer-action-interceptor)