# Dynamic React Redux Header component in large application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a Header component which is used throughout my application. I'm using React and Redux (obvz) to hold a default state for the Header e.g. in the header reducer's default state argument:

```
state = { 
     showUserMenu: true,
     redirectUrl: '/'
}
```

This is perfect for all the components where this is true, but for some routes/components I want the header to **not** show the user menu.

So when those components mount I dispatch an action to HIDE_USER_MENU.

The problem is that because the default is set to true, the userMenu will be there initially, *and even if the dispatch is called in componentWillMount*, there will be a split second where the userMenu shows.

So don't have a default? But then the reverse is true, it defaults to not showing the menu and only appears once the action has processed.

[This is nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303028/react-redux-displaying-multiple-components-sharing-same-actions-but-with-diff), but it didn't go just a step further (for my example) and explain how the reducer would be chosen based on either route or component.

I have also tried firing actions based on location.pathname using [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), but even this does not happen quickly enough to avoid FOUH (flash of unwanted header! :'(  )

I wondered if there was an established pattern for dynamically loading an initial state, that is guaranteed to appear on initial render.

Hope it's clear what I was asking, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to have the Header be a child of the route. This makes it easy to decide what props to pass:
* You don't need to store the header state at all - the routed component can just pass the appropriate props (such as showUserMenu) to the Header.

However, it has a couple of downsides:
* All routes have to take care of rendering the Header (not really a problem, there are lots of ways to share the code)
* When re-routing, the Header is unmounted and a new one mounted (since its parent, the route component, is unmounted). So any DOM and React state will be lost.

The unmount could be avoided by using the same component type for all your routes (which could render the header), but pass it props to configure the appropriate route handling behaviour (such as a child component).

Another (probably bad) option is for your Header state listen for redux-react-router's LOCATION_CHANGE action, and change the value of showUserMenu based on that. The documentation appears to advise against this, since there can be some asynchronicity before the new route is actually rendered due to dynamic route loading, etc., but it probably works fine for the normal case.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Tom! I am aware that I could render the header within each component but that's exactly what I was trying to get away from with this. Having a header rendered in 50+ components all with different configurations is painfully un-DRY :(. Also when I mentioned firing actions based on location.pathname using react-redux-router, I was using history.listen e.g. LOCATION_CHANGE. Unfortunately (as you alluded to) that has the same effect. I've also tried wrapping the header in a higher-order component, same problem...

Comment: If all the components have different configurations, then there isn't any repetition ;) ! Seriously though, including if you factor everything out into components like StandardScreen (e.g. one route might be `<StandardScreen includeMenu={true}><UserPage/></StandardScreen>`), then that's configuration for a route, not repetition. That said, you almost certainly will need to update store state as part of routing at some point: if you use history.listen and have the callback dispatch your own routeChanged action, does that give you a workable hook to update your store state before the render?

Comment: Sorry was away on hols! I get what you mean, but for me this is exactly what Redux is there for: to handle state across your whole application, which is all I'm trying to do with it. So you know, my code for updating the state is already in the history.listen callback e.g: `history.listen(location => dispatch(hideUserMenu())); ` There is some conditional stuff in there to check which route I'm on, but that's it!

Comment: I agree it is definitely vital to be able to synchronously update state in response to routing in many large apps (my own app uses this facility extensively to initialise store state from routing args, but I'm using my own flux + routing libraries). I'm surprised you get the flicker on your render, since I would have thought that the re-render happens without any 'yield' back to the browser. A double render implies your history listener is being called asynchronously. It would be worth putting a breakpoint in your render method and checking the call-stack for the 2 calls.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Tom. I'm accepting this as your help and info helped towards a solution with quite a vague question! Ultimately it's working now as long as it's in SPA mode. There is a delay when loading on a hard reload but I'm happy with that for now.